# When I cut a layer using marquee tool, I get blur edges to cut side. How do I get sharp edges after cut?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs5, blur, marquee-tool

I am using rectangular marquee tool to cut a portion of the layer in photoshop cs5, but after cutting, the edges are not sharp, I get blur edges.
[image]   [image]

how can I get sharp edges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you have `Feather` set to something that is not 0. Make sure it is set to 0 px.

[image: Marquee Feather]